# Flask - The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Yesterday I started getting this error and just can't figure out what it might be. I cut my Flask API down to the bare minimum and it is still not working.

Here is my file structure (excluding requirements.txt and .ebextensions/python.config):

```
modules/
   test.py
application.py
```

Here is application.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

import modules.test

application = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(application)

class test(Resource):
    def get(self):

        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

        parser.add_argument('string', required=True)

        args = parser.parse_args()

        try:
            response = modules.test.run(args['string'])
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            return "400 | " + str(e)
    pass

api.add_resource(test, '/test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8080", debug=True)
```

Here is test.py

```
def run(string):
    return string
```

When I try on my local system, everything is working fine. When I deploy this to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk enviroment and make a request like:

```
https://example.com/test?string=hello
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}
```

I cannot figure out what might be causing this issue. I have also tried deploying on DigitalOcean but it is the same. This has been working fine forever and suddenly it breaks.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the console / log of Flask!

Comment: what's your request headers?